# Unable To Open Database File Error

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, file

I'm having troubles with SQLite and C#. Wherever I put my .db file, when I try to open it and create tables I get the error "unable to open database file".

I first wanted to put it in the `%appdata%` folder, then I tried to put it in several other places like `userprofile` or `local appdata`, even in the Desktop just to see if it worked. The error still appeared, so I created the .db file (the .db file is created through code) without the file path, in order to having it in the debug folder, and the error didn't show up.

So, I don't think that permissions are involved, because I even tried on the Desktop and I also tried to open the created .db file with a database browser to see if it could be corrupted, and it worked like a charm.

What could the problem be? Thank you all in advance for the help!

**EDIT:**

Here are the `Connection String` and path variables:

```
static string dbConnectionString = "Data Source=" + Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\CSB_Ore\csb_ore.sqlite;";
string dbFilePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\CSB_Ore\csb_ore.sqlite";
string dbFolderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\CSB_Ore";
```

and here are the methods for the database creation:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Check if the database exists. If not, the database is created and also the CSB_Days table.
    /// </summary>
    public void FirstTimeExecution()
    {
        if(!Directory.Exists(dbFolderPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dbFolderPath);
            File.Create(dbFilePath);

            string tableCreationOutput = CreateTables();

            if (tableCreationOutput == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Tables successfully created.", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error while creating tables:\n\n" + tableCreationOutput, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }

    public string CreateTables()
    {
        string createDaysTableScript = "CREATE TABLE 'CSBO_Days' ("
                                        + "`ID` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                                        + "`Date`   datetime,"
                                        + "`Hours`  decimal(2, 2),"
                                        + "`IsPartTime` bit,"
                                        + "`Notes`  TEXT"
                                        + ")";
        try
        {
            dbConnection.Open();
            SQLiteCommand createTablesCommand = new SQLiteCommand(createDaysTableScript, dbConnection);
            createTablesCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return null;
        }
        catch(SQLiteException ex)
        {
            return ex.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            dbConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I simply create the folder and the .db file in case that they don't exist, then I call the method for the table creation and return the eventual exception to see if the table has been created.

**EDIT 2**:

As requested, this is the `dbConnectionString` output just before the `dbConnection.Open()`:

[image]

Comment: In order to accurately answer your question, it would help to see what code you are using.

Comment: The problem likely is that the code is wrong.

Comment: Can you display `dbConnection.ConnectionString` before `Open()`? or debug and paste the text here.

Comment: @LeiYang I noticed that after the database has been created, if I close the program and restart the application executing `CreateTables()` I don't get the error and the table is successfully created. Any idea?